# How to move instances so that they move from a certain point and finally create a face

Tags: animation, instances

i want to make an animation like attached picture; in blender of course, something like, all instances comes out from one point and create a face like this, how should i do that?[image]

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Something like this https://youtu.be/Vmax39A-ehc
with a reverse of this?
https://youtu.be/xlVuIh3td9g also this https://youtu.be/igPnuEQ7RB4

Answer (score 4):

This is not a full answer, rather me sharing a setup I created a while ago:

[image]

You can probably tell by looking at a node tree, it's a combination of a less experienced past myself and older Blender (probably works in 3.0), so the setup could be modernized…

It allows to control with weight-paint the order of triangles thanosing:

[image]

[image]

The triangles move through each-other and the original mesh, there is no collision detection. For your purposes you would reverse the animation, which is trivial, however if you want one object to turn to another, you would need to make sure both have the same number of triangles. If you want to replace triangles with flower petals or whatever, you could do normal → align euler to vector → capture attribute (face domain) → mesh to points (faces mode) → instance on points (and use captured euler + the flower petal instance/s)

[image]

Comment: +1 For inventing the word "*thanosing*" and successfully using in in an answer :D

Answer (score 3):

An old-school method would be to use [Keyed Physics](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/particles/emitter/physics/keyed.html), on matched particle systems.

Perhaps the most controllable way is to set up 3 particle systems. One each on the source and target objects, and one on a dummy transition object. The source and target systems have normal particle effects, perhaps involving curve-guides or force-fields. The transition system is keyed between the other two:

[image]

I'm not sure it would be very helpful to share a file.. it's all in the settings, which will be very different case-to-case, and I won't pretend they aren't quite fiddly.

There's quite a nice reference [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lPCs4XbGth8).

If you go this way and  get stuck on a particular aspect, you can come back with a more specific question.